# PYTHON - Can't figure out why I am getting this error when trying to send a message to an email address. b'550 5.7.1 Relaying not allowed:

Tags: python, sockets, email, networking

I'm trying to send an email from one email address to another using sockets in python. How do I fix this issue that I am having?

I tried Disabling the firewall, trying other servers, and trying different ports.

```
from socket import *
msg = "\r\n I love computer networks!"
endmsg="\r\n.\r\n"
mailfrom = "MAIL FROM:<*********@gmail.com>\r\n"
rcptto="RCPT TO:<*********@gmail.com>\r\n"
data = "DATA\r\n"
quitmsg="QUIT\r\n"
subject = "Subject: Computer Networks SMTP Programming project Test\r\n"


#choose a mail server
mailserver="smtp.o2.ie"
port=25
connectaddress=(mailserver,port)
```

We are supposed to get the msg that we defined in the rcptto email. Instead we are getting this -> b'250 2.5.0 Address Ok.\r\n'
b'550 5.7.1 Relaying not allowed:

Comment: The mail server at `smtp.o2.ie` is most likely rejecting your message because you are not authenticated / permitted to use the relay.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was figuring. I created my own Domain so I use the localhost, and I feel like I am close. 
b'220 LAPTOP-692TUOC4 ESMTP\r\n'
b'250 Hello.\r\n'
b'250 OK\r\n'
b'250 OK\r\n'
b'354 OK, send.\r\n'
b'250 Queued (0.015 seconds)\r\n'
b'221 goodbye\r\n'
Mail sent
I am getting this in the command line, but no email to my address.

Comment: You also can't _just create your own domain_ :) Setting up a mail server is actually quite a bit of work to get other server to actually accept mail from your host. It's likely that the message is still just sitting in the local queue. SSH to the host and run `postqueue -p` It's even more likely that your ISP blocks SMPT port 25, so if you try to run this from your home, you won't be able to relay anything. You will most likely need a cloud VPS which will allows SMTP connections.

Comment: You should really just look into use an SMTP library, because your methods here will not support authentication or encryption. All libraries that you find will support both basic authentication, which will allow you to actually access the relay, in addition to providing support for SSL.

Comment: Okay thank you for your help! I will look into what you suggested!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the program does not have permission to use the email addresses to send the message. Something similar happened to me when i was using i different package to send emails via Python.Check [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gzv183G9Vew) For sending emails using python another way.

Comment: I do not want to use the smtp library.  Instead of using smtp.o2.ie, I created my own domain. I feeel like I am close...receiving this response;
b'220 LAPTOP-692TUOC4 ESMTP\r\n'
b'250 Hello.\r\n'
b'250 OK\r\n'
b'250 OK\r\n'
b'354 OK, send.\r\n'
b'250 Queued (0.015 seconds)\r\n'
b'221 goodbye\r\n'
Mail sent
But I'm not getting any response to my actual email address I placed as my receiver.

Answer (score 0):

I made a fix -- Instead of using google, yahoo etc...I used an email address linked to the ISP I use and was able to successfully send the message to the email. EX -> Exampleuser@chart.net. Thanks for the help!

Comment: And for the server, I used one from my ISP with port 25.